# Can we use LAZY LOADING on One-to-many Relationship in Hibernate 5?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I tried to use LAZY LOADING when loading information of Match without list of live links. But the result always fetch all links in Match.

**My question is: 
Is it possible to use LAZY LOAD for One-to-many relationship in Hibernate 5? If we can, please help me to check my code.**

**Thank you very much!**

I have following code:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "match_info")
public class MatchInfoModel extends AuditModel {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "MATCH_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long matchId;

    @Column(name = "STADIUM_NAME")
    private String stadiumName;

    @Column(name = "START_TIME")
    private Date startTime;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "matchInfoModel", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    private Set<LiveStreamModel> liveStreamsSet;    
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "live_stream")
public class LiveStreamModel extends AuditModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LIVE_LINK_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long liveLinkId;

    @Column(name = "LINK")
    private String link;

    @Column(name = "SPEED")
    private String speed;

    @Column(name = "ORDER_NUMBER")
    private int orderNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "MATCH_ID")
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private MatchInfoModel matchInfoModel;
}
```

My Query function:

```
@Override
    public List<MatchInfoModel> getLiveMatches() throws Exception {

        Session session = getSession();
        CriteriaBuilder criteria = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<MatchInfoModel> criteriaQuery = criteria.createQuery(MatchInfoModel.class);
        Root<MatchInfoModel> matchInfoRoot = criteriaQuery.from(MatchInfoModel.class);
        criteriaQuery.select(matchInfoRoot);

        // Order by start time
        criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteria.asc(matchInfoRoot.get("startTime")));
        return session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
    }
```

My TRACE log:

```
2018-08-13 10:00:24 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        matchinfom0_.match_id as match_id1_4_,
        matchinfom0_.creat_date as creat_da2_4_,
        matchinfom0_.create_user as create_u3_4_,
        matchinfom0_.last_modified as last_mod4_4_,
        matchinfom0_.modified_user as modified5_4_,
        matchinfom0_.guest_team_id as guest_t10_4_,
        matchinfom0_.has_live_stream as has_live6_4_,
        matchinfom0_.host_team_id as host_te11_4_,
        matchinfom0_.league_name as league_n7_4_,
        matchinfom0_.stadium_name as stadium_8_4_,
        matchinfom0_.start_time as start_ti9_4_ 
    from
        match_info matchinfom0_ 
    order by
        matchinfom0_.start_time asc
2018-08-13 10:00:25 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [1]
2018-08-13 10:00:25 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        livestream0_.match_id as match_i12_3_0_,
        livestream0_.live_link_id as live_lin1_3_0_,
        livestream0_.live_link_id as live_lin1_3_1_,
        livestream0_.creat_date as creat_da2_3_1_,
        livestream0_.create_user as create_u3_3_1_,
        livestream0_.last_modified as last_mod4_3_1_,
        livestream0_.modified_user as modified5_3_1_,
        livestream0_.language as language6_3_1_,
        livestream0_.link as link7_3_1_,
        livestream0_.link_type as link_typ8_3_1_,
        livestream0_.match_id as match_i12_3_1_,
        livestream0_.order_number as order_nu9_3_1_,
        livestream0_.speed as speed10_3_1_,
        livestream0_.status as status11_3_1_ 
    from
        live_stream livestream0_ 
    where
        livestream0_.match_id=?
2018-08-13 10:00:25 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [7]
2018-08-13 10:00:25 DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - 
    select
        livestream0_.match_id as match_i12_3_0_,
        livestream0_.live_link_id as live_lin1_3_0_,
        livestream0_.live_link_id as live_lin1_3_1_,
        livestream0_.creat_date as creat_da2_3_1_,
        livestream0_.create_user as create_u3_3_1_,
        livestream0_.last_modified as last_mod4_3_1_,
        livestream0_.modified_user as modified5_3_1_,
        livestream0_.language as language6_3_1_,
        livestream0_.link as link7_3_1_,
        livestream0_.link_type as link_typ8_3_1_,
        livestream0_.match_id as match_i12_3_1_,
        livestream0_.order_number as order_nu9_3_1_,
        livestream0_.speed as speed10_3_1_,
        livestream0_.status as status11_3_1_ 
    from
        live_stream livestream0_ 
    where
        livestream0_.match_id=?
2018-08-13 10:00:25 TRACE o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [BIGINT] - [6]
```

Comment: *But the result always fetch all links in Match.* - how do you know?

Comment: Can you enable org.hibernate.sql and  org.hibernate.types log in TRACE mode and copy the query which executes the query for LiveStreamModel to fetch the record when you load MatchInfoModel

Comment: Thank for your comment. I have just add TRACE log. Please help me to check!

Comment: Are you doing anything in your code after getting getLiveMatches().

Comment: No. I just response to client-side

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of-course we can use, lazy loading in @OneToMany relationship.

Just do this

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
private Set<LiveStreamModel> liveStreamsSet;
```

More info [OnetoOne](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and [OneToMany](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thank for your answer. But when I add @MapsId, it cause problem: "nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Unknown entity name: java.util.Set"